# How to run mariadb replication without error?

Tags: ansible, mariadb, mysql-replication

I set up a master to slave replication according to the docs. I'm using ansible for this (see below).

After the initial run (lock, backup, unlock, copy to slave host, import and start slave) the slave status is

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
```

This tells me: the replication works.

After some time (maybe a minute or so - the server is not that frequently used right now), this changes, and SHOW SLAVE STATUS shows

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: No
Last_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table nextcloud.oc_calendarobjects; Can't find record in 'oc_calendarobjects', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log master2-bin.000019, end_l
og_pos 19897439
Last_IO_Error:
Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table nextcloud.oc_calendarobjects; Can't find record in 'oc_calendarobjects', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log master2-bin.000019, end_l
og_pos 19897439
Slave_SQL_Running_State:
```

This tells me: as soon as there's a change on the master, the replication stops because of some weirdness.

I have no idea if it's special to a nextcloud database, because I saw this issue always happening there, but it's also the only database with frequent changes.

I tried it with

```
CHANGE MASTER TO ... MASTER_USE_GTID=no;
```

as well as

```
CHANGE MASTER TO ... MASTER_USE_GTID=slave_pos;
```

and setting `--gtid` on the `mysqldump`. Same behavior.

What am I missing here?
How can I make the replication actually work (without having to rerun everything once there's a change on master, which would be same as triggering manually)?

## Ansible setup / Commands executed

I'm using ansible to set up master-slave replication, running over all hosts, but performing tasks only on master or slave respectively.
Shell commands executed are at the end.

From the docs I get that using `--master-data` in `mysqldump` automatically flushes, locks and unlocks after dumping.

```
- name: Get current timestamp
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  ansible.builtin.command: date +%F_%T
  register: datetime_run
  changed_when: true
- name: Set current timestamp
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    datetime: "{{ datetime_run.stdout }}"

- name: Backup all databases for replication
  when: inventory_hostname == mariadb_master_host
  community.mysql.mysql_db:
    login_user: admin
    login_password: "{{ passwd }}"
    config_file: ""
    state: dump
    master_data: 1
    dump_extra_args: "--apply-slave-statements"
    # --gtid
    name:
      - db1
      - db2
      - nextcloud
    target: "/tmp/mariadb.dump.{{ datetime }}.sql.gz"
    pipefail: true

- name: Copy DB dump from master
  when: inventory_hostname != mariadb_master_host
  ansible.builtin.synchronize:
    src: "/tmp/mariadb.dump.{{ datetime }}.sql.gz"
    dest: /tmp
  delegate_to: "{{ mariadb_master_host }}"

- name: Stop slave
  when: inventory_hostname != mariadb_master_host
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_user: admin
    login_password: "{{ passwd.stdout }}"
    query: STOP SLAVE;

- name: Configure Slave
  when: inventory_hostname != mariadb_master_host
  # no_log: true
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_user: admin
    login_password: "{{ passwd.stdout }}"
    query: |
      CHANGE MASTER TO
        MASTER_HOST='{{ mariadb_master_host }}',
        MASTER_USER='replication',
        MASTER_PASSWORD='{{ db_replication_password }}',
        MASTER_PORT=3306,
        MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10,
        MASTER_USE_GTID=no;
    # =slave_pos

- name: Import MariaDB Dump to start replication
  when: inventory_hostname != mariadb_master_host
  community.mysql.mysql_db:
    login_user: admin
    login_password: "{{ passwd.stdout }}"
    state: import
    target: "/tmp/mariadb.dump.{{ datetime }}.sql.gz"
    name: all
    config_file: ""
    pipefail: true
    use_shell: true

- name: Show SLAVE Status
  when: inventory_hostname != mariadb_master_host
  community.mysql.mysql_info:
    login_user: admin
    login_password: "{{ passwd.stdout }}"
    config_file: ""
    filter: "slave_status"
  register: out
  failed_when: out.slave_status[mariadb_master_host]['3306'].replication['Slave_IO_Running'] != 'Yes' or out.slave_status[mariadb_master_host]['3306'].replication['Slave_SQL_Running'] != 'Yes'
```

The actual executed mysql commands are

```
set -o pipefail && /usr/bin/mysqldump --user=admin --password='********' --host=localhost --port=3306 --databases db1 db2 nextcloud --quick --master-data=1 --apply-slave-statements | /usr/bin/gzip > /tmp/mariadb.dump.2023-10-17_18:10:11.sql.gz
```

and

```
/usr/bin/gzip -dc /tmp/mariadb.dump.2023-10-17_18:10:11.sql.gz | /usr/bin/mysql --user=admin --password='********' --host=localhost --port=3306
```

## Full Status Output

### Master

```
            File: master2-bin.000019
        Position: 66117642
    Binlog_Do_DB: db1,db2,nextcloud
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
```

### Slave

```
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: my-master-host
                   Master_User: replication
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 10
               Master_Log_File: master2-bin.000019
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 66117642
                Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 2068159
         Relay_Master_Log_File: master2-bin.000019
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: No
               Replicate_Do_DB: db1,db2,nextcloud
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 1032
                    Last_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table nextcloud.oc_calendarobjects; Can't find record in 'oc_calendarobjects', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log master2-bin.000019, end_log_pos 62885990
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 62877650
               Relay_Log_Space: 4117044
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
                Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table nextcloud.oc_calendarobjects; Can't find record in 'oc_calendarobjects', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log master2-bin.000019, end_log_pos 62885990
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 2
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State:
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 670
```

Comment: How do you check that your import isn't failing and you have data in the DB? Also, `--master-data` includes the `CHANGE MASTER` command in the dump so it overwrites whatever your ansible command does.

Answer (score 1):

Your databases were out of sync before executing that command from the binlog. Repeat the initial setup.

Do make sure this is running as master/slave, not master/master - and slave should be set to read-only mode.

Comment: I did this several times and it always happened. According to the docs, one can release the lock as soon as the dump is written, because everything new goes into the binlog already. So how can DB be out of sync? On the slave DB, nothing is written to the DB. Want to understand this, even if I may want to switch to master-master mode.

Comment: I don't know what the ansible job is doing - can't comment. on that, but I believe that, to get a consistent backup, you need --lock-all-tables